# Does adding tags to a question generally increase the number of responses I get?

Tags: discussion, tags, asking-questions, responses

Maybe because some people might only subscribe to tags rather than to an entire stackexchange site?

And is this also dependent on what stackexchange site it is?

Comment: Probably. There is also a related phenomenon some call "tag shotgun," where people add possibly irrelevant tags to maximize views.

Comment: Indeed; tag-shotgunning is a great way to irritate the people who are trying to help you.

Comment: I'd think making sure relevant tags are included would help, I know I generally only look at the SO questions that are highlighted from being in my followed tags unless I'm super bored.

Comment: I make it a point to downvote every other question with all of these tags together: [html][css][css3][css-selectors][css-floating] And then retag them. There are a couple of users who tag their questions like this *every single time* and they just don't seem to get it...

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Have you tried leaving comments that spell it out for them?

Comment: @Anna Lear: Well, not yet. Maybe I should.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The effect of adding relevant tags is to make the question visible to more users, who are then the users who can reply to the question.
This doesn't automatically means more answers, as you could ask a question that needs to be understood before to be answered, or requires that somebody tests what you are reporting.

For sure there are more eyes on your question, especially if there are users who are notified for new questions using the tags they are following, or who can get a list of questions using specific tags.

That is the reason to choose the appropriate tag. If you (for example) tag a Drupal question with [php](/questions/tagged/php), it is probable you will get less answers than when you also add [drupal](/questions/tagged/drupal), or any related tags.

Answer (score 9):

Sure, choosing *relevant* tags can help draw attention to your questions.

I don't know if it'll necessarily increase the number of responses (I have no data to claim either way), but it certainly can't hurt.

This may have less effect on smaller sites where the question volume is low enough that most people will see all new questions as they come up.